# error "can't read property isPlaying" when trying to play audio file

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I was getting started with the p5js library and I was trying to play an audio file on mouse click but I keep on getting error `Cannot read property 'isPlaying' of undefined`. I have defined variable song in the global scope and ```isPlaying is an p5js synatax that returns a boolean which I have imported as cdn in my HTML file. I cant figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
var song;

function preLoad() {
  song = loadSound('pathToAudio')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(0)
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (song.isPlaying()) { //error initiate here
    song.pause()
  } else {
    song.play()
  }
}
```

```html
<!--CDN for p5js library-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I'd stary with basic troubleshooting: is the path to the audio file correct ? Is the audio file served (at least on a local web server) ? Does it load/play correctly in the browser directly (e.g. check encoding/decoding errors) ? If the previous are true, has the song fully loaded before clicking ? Were there any errors loading the song ? (Notice in the [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadSound) you can pass a success and error callback as the second and third arguments to see what's going on)

Comment: Most likely a typo: `preLoad` should be `preload`. (note the casing of the letter L). My guess is "preLoad" is never called.

Comment: yes it was the case issue thanks for your help.